# How does TestFlight Live work?

Tags: ios, app-store, testflight

Is it possible to use TestFlight Live for analytics and crash reports for my App Store submitted app?

If so, how does it work? Can I get symbolicated crashes? The documentation for TestFlight Live is not very extensive. I know it's beta, but I'd like to know more about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use Testflight Live for "some" analitics, like how many current users, nr of unique users used your app, how many sessions, avg time for a session etc.

It's best to try it yourself to test. It's easy to setup, include the SDK in your project, and then one line of code to takeoff.
You can do more things, like adding code so you can show questions to your testers after finishing level 1 asking if it was too easy or not (as an example).

Symbolication is possible, you can upload your .dSYM file.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Crashlytics](http://beta.crashlytics.com) for your crash reports. It's very lightweight and easy to setup. It also gives very detailed (which line the program crashed) results.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but it was not at all an answer to my question